# An AJAX call with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to learn how to make an AJAX call using vanilla JavaScript in an effort to move away from JQuery for a little project that I'm working on but don't seem to be getting past `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`. Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong (the function `getDVDsAndBluRays()` is getting invoked on `DOMContentLoaded`)? Thanks!

```
function getDVDsAndBluRays() {
  console.log("Getting logged");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=metropolis&y=&plot=short&r=json';

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Not getting logged");
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
      var myMovies = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      myFunction(myMovies);

    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  };
}    

function myFunction(myMovies) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myMovies.length; i++) {
    var title = myMovies[i].Title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('+');
    var year = myMovies[i].Year;
    console.log(title + ", " + "year");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your .open() and .send() inside your onreadystatechange() handler. Put those outside of the onreadystatechange function and you should be good to go.

Onreadystatechange() is the event handler for when there is a change in state in the xmlhttp request, and will not get called until you open the request and send it.

Hope this helped!

Comment: It did! Thanks very much for explaining it.

Answer (score 4):

It should be like that, notice the location of open and send functions:

```
function getDVDsAndBluRays() {

  console.log("Getting logged");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=metropolis&y=&plot=short&r=json';
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Not getting logged");
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      console.log('responseText:' + xmlhttp.responseText);
      var myMovies = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      myFunction(myMovies);

    }

  };
}    

function myFunction(myMovies) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myMovies.length; i++) {
    var title = myMovies[i].Title.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('+');
    var year = myMovies[i].Year;
    console.log(title + ", " + "year");
  }
}
```

onreadystatechange is executed after the call, you were actually "calling the service when it replies"

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have put the calls to `open` and `send` **inside** the `onreadystatechange` event handler so they will never be called.

Move them outside it.

Comment: Thank you! Will do.